# Holder JS not working in ASP.net update panel

Tags: javascript, updatepanel, holder.js

I am using [Holder.js](http://imsky.github.io/holder/) to genearte client side images.

If I write

```
<img src="holder.js/300x200">
```

it works..!
But if I write the same thing in an update panel the image is not generated.
When I inspect the element using chrome tools, the image is rendered with correct Image URL but does not display the image.
Why is this happening? and any solutions to it?

My Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepnlReppeaterSummary" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterSummary" runat="server">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <img src="holder.js/300x200">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute `Holder.run` after every DOM update. Make sure to call `Holder.run` on the `pageLoad` event or another callback.

Comment: Thank you.! It worked.! Sorry I was not able to mark this as an answer before.. :)